# Prove that the cardinality of a finite orbit under the action of a $p$-group is a power of $p$

Tags: group-theory

It's easy to see that an immediate corollary of orbit-stabilizer is that the orbit of any element under the action of a *finite* $p$-group has cardinality a power of $p$ (this question is not a duplicate, as the related questions only show the result for finite groups).

Naturally, I've tried to generalize the idea to infinite groups, but to no avail. That is to say, if $G$ is an infinite
$p$-group which acts on a set $X$, such that the orbit of some $x \in X$ is finite, we would like to show that the size of said orbit is a power of $p$.

Some ideas so far: We know that the size of the orbit of $x$ is equal to $[G : G_x]$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ (by orbit stabilizer). Then, if it were the case that $[G : G_x]$ had a different prime factor $q \neq p$, we could write $q \mid |G / G_x|$. However, we can't exactly apply Cauchy's theorem here, because $G / G_x$ is not necessarily a group. My next idea was to try to find some nontrivial quotient group on which we *could* apply Cauchy's theorem, but I haven't been successful thus far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a $p$-group, each element has order which is a power of $p$. For any element $\alpha\in G$ you can consider the subgroup generated entirely by $\left<\alpha\right>$. Now you've reduced to the finite case, which you've done.

Comment: @Laarz The finite case will show us that the orbit of $x$ under action by $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is a power of $p$. But what can we say about the orbit under action by the entire group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $G_x$ is a subgroup of finite index in $G$ there is a normal subgroup $N$ contained in $G_x$ which also has finite index in $G$. (Well-known result I believe.)

I think that's all you need.

Comment: This would prove the result, but I wasn't aware of this fact about groups. Thanks!